# php date addition skipping days

Tags: php, date

I have a date, and need to add 24 Months ***(and not 2 Year)*** to it. This is what I tried:

```
strtotime("+24 months", $mydate);
```

If my date is, `20th Dec 2013` then the computed date is coming as `10th Dec 2015`, whereas my expected date was `20th Dec 2015`.

I know, what is going behind the scene:

```
2 Year: 365 days x 2 = 730 days
24 Months: 24 x 30days = 720 days
```

This gives me the missing 10 days. But how to over come this issue.

In `Java` we have `Calendar` class, which takes care of such calculations. However, I din't find anything here.

Can this issue be resolved.? Or I need to handle it manually?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this using `$mydate=strtotime("2013-12-20");` - maybe your starting date assumption is wrong? Which version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$mydate = "2014-10-01";
echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime("+24 months", strtotime($mydate)));
```

Comment: Surely you should use DateTime wherever possible as then any date methods that you use can be typehinted

Answer (score 2):

You should always use the DateTime() class for anything like that.

i.e

```
$date = new DateTime("UTC");

//get date in 24months time:
$date->add(new DateInterval("P24M"));

//output date:
echo $date->format("d/m/Y H:i:s");
```

By using the DateTime and DateInterval classes, you can be sure that it will account of leap years and other such irregularities in dates.

See more at: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) should work perfectly here:

```
$date = new DateTime("20th Dec 2013");
echo $date->format("d-m-Y");
$date->add(new DateInterval('P24M'));
echo $date->format("d-m-Y");
```

Output:

```
20-12-2013
20-12-2015
```

**[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MdzP7R)**

**Sidenote:**

I couldn't reproduce your error with:

```
echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime("+24 months", $mydate = strtotime("2013-12-20")));
```

See:
    http://3v4l.org/HURAt